# Why the php code does not enter the user data from the form into the array

Tags: php, arrays

This is html for the registration of the new user but what if instead of entering the values again and again by $_POST[ ], I just want to enter the values into the array and then copy them to the database.

But the php code is not entering the all the form values to the array, it just prints me the first value of the form i.e. Firstname

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="userregcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="adduser">
<img src="user_male_2_add.ico" id="imguser" height="20px" width="20px" />
<span id="usercon">Add User</span>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<form action="userregphp.php" method="post" id="fm">
First Name<input type="text" id="fn" placeholder="Enter your first name" size="40"    name="1" required="required" title="please enter the first name" /><br  />
Last Name<input type="text" id="ln" placeholder="Enter your last name" size="40"  name="2" required="required"/><br  />
Address<textarea id="address" name="3" rows="10" cols="20" required="required">  </textarea><br  />
E-mail<input type="email" id="email" name="4" placeholder="Please enter your email" size="40" required="required" /><br  /> 
Retype Email<input type="email" id="remail" name="5" placeholder="Please retype your   email" size="40" required="required" />    <br />
Username<input type="text" id="un"  name="6" placeholder="Please enter your username" disabled="disabled" size="40" required="required" /><br  />
Password<input type="password" required="required" id="pass" name="7"  placeholder="Please enter your password" size="40"  /><br  />
Phone number<input type="text" id="phoneno" name="8" placeholder="Please enter your phone number" size="40" required="required"  /><br  />
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="add user"  /> 
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the php code

```
<?php
require "dbconnect.php";
function insert()
{
    $add = array();
    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
        for($i=1; ; $i++)
        {
            array_push($add, $_POST[$i]);
            if($i = 8)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($add as $value)
    {
        echo($value);
    }

}
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $un, $pass, $db);
if(!$connect)
{
    die("connection error". mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();
}
else
{
    insert();
}

?>
```

Comment: Why not `for($i=1; $i < 9; $i++)` ? Uh ... Worse when coupled with `if ($i = 8)` instead of `==`

Comment: If you want to pre-fill the form, shouldn't you be binding the $add data into the HTML? Like: `First Name<input type="text" value="<?php echo $add[$name_index]; ?>" ...`

Comment: Because `echo` will just print the `$add` value at the location of the php script...

Comment: It gives me an error of undefined offset on line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you also have an undefined offset error, you could just do it that way :

```
foreach ($_POST as $post_value) {
  array_push($add, $post_value); // or $add[] = $post_value
}
```

Not saying it's the perfect way to do it, but naming POST parameters with 1, 2, 3 ... is worse I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require "dbconnect.php";
function insert()
{
    $add = array();
    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
        for($i=1; $i < 9; $i++) //This is incomplete
        {
            array_push($add, $_POST[$i]);
            if($i == 8) //This needs to be == and not just =
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($add as $value)
    {
        echo($value);
    }

}
$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $un, $pass, $db);
if(!$connect)
{
    die("connection error". mysqli_connect_errno());
    exit();
}
else
{
    insert();
}

?>
```

I have fixed the things wrong with your code and commented where they are.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function insert()
{
    $add = array();
    if($_POST['submit'])
    {
        $i=0;
        for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++)
        {
           array_push($add, $_POST[$i]);
        } 
    }
    foreach($add as $value)
    {
        echo($value);
    }

}
```